# Explorer tab in VS Code not tracking file colors anymore

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code and for some reason, the Explorer tab no longer tracks file colors according to file changes. I have installed the GitLens extension.

Here is my `settings.json` file:

```json
{
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false
}
```

I have even tried reinstalling VS Code, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check *all* your [settings files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) (user settings.json file, workspace .vscode/settings.json file, and multi-root workspace .code-workspace file (if you are using multi-root workspaces)), or check in the settings UI. I suspect you have `"explorer.decorations.colors": false` set somewhere. If that's not the case, it could be a bug, or interference from an extension, in which case you can try doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect).